# Requires: hostname while trying to install Fish Shell

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, yum, fish

I'm trying to install Fish Shell on an updated Amazon Linux machine, I keep getting the error:

`Requires: hostname`

I tried both repositories offered on the Fish Shell website for CentOS 6 and 7, delete both before trying the other. Nettools is installed, it's a standard Amazon Linux install, so it has all the basics. If anyone can help it would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not exactly a programming question and would be better placed in [superuser@stackexchange](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2062

Both a strength and weakness of fish is that it depends more heavily on external commands than shells like bash or zsh. You need to explicitly install whatever package provides the `hostname` command for your OS. In the future we intend to make the dependency implicit when installing fish.

Comment: Also, please open issues against fish at https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/new if you believe your issue has not already been communicated to the fish team.